# Javascript - storing the index of all array values in a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-variables

Say I have an array in JS:  var fruits = [apple,orange,banana]
I want to store the index of each fruit in variables such that at any point in time, if I add more stuff to the array, I will still know that the index of apple is X.  So in this case,  0 is apple, but if I add something to the beginning of that away, the index of apple changes.

The more verbose way I can think of is to loop through the array

```
for (var i=0;i<fruits.length;i++) {
   switch(fruits[i]) {
    case:"apple"
      var indexApple = i;
      break;
    //etc 
   }
}
```

Another way I can think of is use the value of the arrays as the variable name.

```
for (var i=0;i<fruits.length;i++) {
  //psedo code
  var 'index' + fruits[i] = i;
}
```

So in the end I'd have var indexApple = 0, indexOrange = 1, etc. THe key to the second method is to be able to create a dynamic variable by concatenating the string 'index' and the value of the array to create that variable.  Not sure how to do that.

Note: Ideally I want the variables that store the index to be dynamically generated.  Such that I only I can modify/add to the fruits array, and a new variable will be generated to store the index.

Comment: Tried to get my head around this (what on earth could be the reason for this), but it only got twisted ...

Comment: Instead of storing index into a variable.You can store it in another array,So it would be easy to fetch it.

Comment: You're not asking the question you have, but instead already proposing a solution. I'm pretty sure the real solution to your problem is entirely different from (and much simpler than) your proposal. So - what are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I have a solution, which would preferably something like the second example, but I don't know the correct syntax to make it work.

Comment: It's not about syntax. This is about describing your *problem*. Describing the solution that you think that could work without describing your actual task does not make much sense. You could easily miss a good solution this way.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like ensuring your the value of the index is legitimate will be difficult.  i would include jquery and use the [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method which returns the index of the item in the array.

```
function showIndexes() {
  var appleIndex = $.inArray(fruits, "Apple"); //returns 0
  var guavaIndex = $.inArray(fruits, "Guava"); //returns -1

  fruits.unshift("Guava");
  appleIndex = $.inArray(fruits, "Apple"); //returns 1
  guavaIndex = $.inArray(fruits, "Guava"); //returns 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is simply to build an Object which gives you nearly O(1) lookup time, and will scale with your array:

```
function LinkFruits(fruits) {
    FruitLookup = {}
    fruits.forEach((fruit,ind) => FruitLookup[fruit] = ind)
}
```

Now you can simply "lookup" your index from the `FruitLookup` table when needed like:

```
console.log("The index of apple is",FruitLookup.apple,"and for orange is",FruitLookup.orange)
```

Now if you modify your array you simply need to run `LinkFruits(fruits)`.

**Technical Note:** If you want to fully automate this process you can look into `Array.observe()` which is now **deprecated**. Or overload the `push` and `pop` methods of this array to trigger the update before falling back to the default prototype methods.